# Funcion sacar_compras() no detecta los values de las keys del diccionario compras = {}

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como ven en el titulo, la funcion no detecta los values y no se porque puede ser. Dejo el codigo aca abajo.
Supongo que es por los compras.value(pr_nom) y el {pr_nom.title()}, ya que ahi es donde me tira error. Despues tambien veran que hay una resta (dos lineas mas abajo) hechas de forma similar, lo que me hace sospechar todavia mas de que sea eso, pero prefiero confirmarlo aca.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
compras = {}
def agregar_compras():
pr_nom = input("Ingresa un elemento para agregar a la lista de compras: ")
pr_can = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad a comprar: "))
compras[pr_nom] = pr_can
if pr_nom in compras:
    if pr_can == 0:
        print("Ingrese una cantidad mayor a 0!")
    else:
        print(compras)
        print("Elemento agregado exitosamente!")
else:
    print("Elemento no fue agregado")

def sacar_compras():
pr_nom = input("Ingrese un elemento a remover: ")
pr_can = int(input("Ingrese una cantidad a remover: "))
# sera este el problema?
if pr_nom in compras:
    print(f"Hay {compras.value(pr_nom)} {pr_nom.title()}")
    if compras.value(pr_nom) in compras >= 1:
        resta = compras.value[pr_nom] - pr_can
        print(f"Te quedan {resta}")
        return resta
    else:
        print("No hay stock suficiente")
else:
    print("Este elemento no estaba ingresado en la lista de compras")
# funcion para remover elementos de la lista de compras
```

Edicion:
1- agregue la funcion `agregar_compras()` para que se entienda mejor la funcion `sacar_compras()`
2- supongamos que decido agregar a la lista un paquete de cigarrillos. Esto supondria que `pr_nom = cigarrillos` y que mi variable `pr_can` seria 1 (cabe aclarar que las variables son locales, no globales). Esto se almacena en el diccionario `compras = {}` gracias a la funcion `agregar_compras()`.
El problema con esto es cuando quiero sacar usando la funcion `sacar_compras()` ya que ni siquiera detecta que cigarrillos esta en el diccionario `compras = {}`.

Comment: En tu ejemplo, _compras_ es un diccionario vacío y nada va coincidir al hacer comparaciones ¿por favor, podrías poner un ejemplo de la información que puede tener para entender mejor la pregunta?

Comment: @EduardoHernández ahi agregue una edicion, disculpa si te falto info!

Comment: La indentación de tu código esta mal, sería bueno que la corrijas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Hola!

He notado varios problemas en el código, primero que nada, en esta parte del código:

```
if pr_nom in compras:
    print(f"Hay {compras.value(pr_nom)} {pr_nom.title()}")
    if compras.value(pr_nom) in compras >= 1:
        resta = compras.value[pr_nom] - pr_can
```

Estas usando como condiciones las variables `pr_nom` y `pr_can`, variables que no tienen ningún valor asignado, si le has asignado un valor, pero dentro de una función, y si esa función no es ejecutada, entonces no tienen valor, deberás integrar el `if` a la función, así, al ejecutarla, deberás especificar el elemento y la cantidad antes, para posteriormente poder sacar las compras, pero deberás primero arreglar otros errores más como el problema de indentación que hay, recuerda que al usar el signo `:` debe haber un espacio de indentación, pasaría de esto:

```
def sacar_compras():
pr_nom = input("Ingrese un elemento a remover: ")
pr_can = int(input("Ingrese una cantidad a remover: "))
```

a esto:

```
def sacar_compras():
    pr_nom = input("Ingrese un elemento a remover: ")
    pr_can = int(input("Ingrese una cantidad a remover: "))
```

Otra cosa, para ejecutar el `if`, deberás antes asignarle un valor a `pr_nom` y a `pc_can`, has hecho un input, pero está en una función externa al procedimiento, siendo el valor que reciba, una variable local, yo te recomendaría integrar el procedimiento a la función misma, quedaría así:

```
if pr_nom in compras:
    print(f"Hay {compras.value(pr_nom)} {pr_nom.title()}")
else:
    print("No hay stock suficiente")
if compras.value(pr_nom) in compras >= 1:
    resta = compras.value[pr_nom] - pr_can
    print(f"Te quedan {resta}")
else:
    print("No hay stock suficiente")
```

Como veras, descarté uno de los `else` que pusiste, porque te dará un error:

```
else:
    print("Este elemento no estaba ingresado en la lista de compras")
```

El `else` como tal te es importante, pero, recuerda que no puede haber un `else` sin un `if`, no puede haber 2 `else` para un mismo `if`, por lo tanto, o creas otro `if`, que quedará mal, o lo agregas a otro `else`, que quedará mal, pero también puedes hacer un bloque `try/except`, que es lo que yo te recomiendo:

```
try:
    if pr_nom in compras:
        print(f"Hay {compras(pr_nom)} {pr_nom.title()}")
    else:
        print("No hay stock suficiente")
    if pr_nom in compras >= 1:
        resta = compras[pr_nom] - pr_can
        print(f"Te quedan {resta}")
    else:
        print("No hay stock suficiente")
except:
    print("Este elemento no estaba ingresado en la lista de compras")
```

Por último, te habrás dado cuenta que yo cambié

```
if compras.value(pr_nom) in compras >= 1:
```

Por:

```
if pr_nom in compras >= 1:
```

Esto es porque, primero, no necesitas usar .value para acceder al valor de algo en un diccionario, tampoco necesitas referirte a compras dos veces, eso te dará error.

Espero haberte aclarado

Comment: Esta es una excelente respuesta!

Comment: Recien veo la respuesta, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Olvidaste introducir los valores al diccionario y luego para obtener el valor es mejor con diccionario.get(clave). Y obtienes el valor de esa clave. Y ver bien las indentaciones
compras = {}

```
def sacar_compras():
  pr_nom = input("Ingrese un elemento a remover: ")
  pr_can = int(input("Ingrese una cantidad a remover: "))
  compras[pr_nom]=pr_can
# sera este el problema?
  if pr_nom in compras:
    print("Hay {} {}".format(compras.get(pr_nom),pr_nom.title()))
    if compras.get(pr_nom) in compras >= 1:
      resta = compras.value[pr_nom] - pr_can
      print('Te quedan {}'.format(resta))
      return resta
    else:
      print("No hay stock suficiente")
  else:
    print("Este elemento no estaba ingresado en la lista de compras")
sacar_compras()
# funcion para remover elementos de la lista tu
```

Comment: cual era el problema y como lo solucionas?

Comment: Gracias Javier! Ahora creo que entiendo mi error, fue usar el value no?
@Christian lo que hace es sacar la funcion .value() que habia usado para cambiarla por get, si no me equivoco.

Comment: @MatiasRico esta es una respuesta de mala calidad, por que no da una explicación de como es que soluciona el problema. Una respuesta que solo muestra el código no es una respuesta

Comment: Recuerda que la respuesta no es solo para ti ni para Matias, **es para TODOS**

Comment: Si es verdad Christian! Gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: Casi, por no decir todas, las respuestas que estás dando son principalmente código. Es importante explicar lo que hace el código y como soluciona el problema. Aunque sea explica lo que hace cada linea de tu código (es lo que yo hago a veces cuando no se me ocurre una mejor forma de dar una explicación). Por que todo esto es importante? Por que así tanto el OP como otras personas que vean tus respuestas más adelante podrán no solo solucionar su problema, si no también aprender por que eso mismo funciona.